# Submit text in input field to my database while adding it to my list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So I am adding some functions to a website and one this is a window where you can enter email addresses that to a list that later on will be used for automatic alert emails.

I've come as far as getting the html and JS code done for adding an email to the list itself but now I'm at the stage where I want to also add it to my database.

Here's the HTML and JS code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1 style="align: center">Lägg till epost-addresser för alerts</h1>
    <input type="text"  id="alertinput"/>
    <button type="submit" id="btn_add">Add</button>
    <div>
        <ul class="alert_ul alertfont">
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
var deleteimage = "<img class='dbtnmargin delbtn' src='img/deleteImg.png'></img>";
$('#btn_add').click(function(){
    $('.alert_ul').append($('<li>', {
    text: $('#alertinput').val()
    }));

    $(".alert_ul li:last").append(deleteimage);
    alertinput.value = '';  
});

$("ul").on("click", '.delbtn', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
</script>
```

I created another PHP file where I understand that I have to write the PHP code for inserting the mail into the DB and then call on the other PHP file with AJAX somehow when I click my submit button (btn_add).

Here's how the other file looks like:

```
<?php
//insert email into DB

require "db/connect.php";

$selectedName = $_POST['postMail'];

if($update = $db->query(
    "INSERT INTO alert_email(mail)
    VALUES ('$selectedMail')"));
?>
```

This is only some kind of shell for how I believe it should look like.

Am I way off? Would be nice with some guidance about how the actual code should look like.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you should validate userinput since you will be inserting it to the database, so doing things like `$_POST['postMail']` is not really safe, because later on you are not filtering this input and SQL injection can happen

Answer (score 0):

one thought is that you should be sanitising the input, and using PDO / bound parameters for security , but another is that you have a discrepancy in the names ($selectedName vs $selectedMail). They should both be the same:

```
$selectedMail= $_POST['postMail'];


if($update = $db->query(
    "INSERT INTO alert_email(mail)
    VALUES ('".$selectedMail."')"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$selectedMail= $_POST['postMail'];

if(isset($_POST['postMail']){

$update = $db->query(
    "INSERT INTO alert_email(mail)
    VALUES ('".$selectedMail."')");
}
```

isset varrible otherwise it will gives you undefined varrible.

Answer (score 0):

OK there are several things to consider here.

First of all, if you call the PHP code every time the user adds an email you also need to do the same if the user clicks the delete button - only with a routine that deletes your entry.
However you should not simply do a

```
'DELETE FROM alert_email WHERE mail="'.$selectedMail.'"'
```

because if the user accidentially enters am email twice and clicks on the deletebutton to remove one of the 2 entries the query above deletes all instances in the db. 
So maybe limit the query to 1 affected row only.

Another thought would be to check for duplicate email addresses in the javascript routine before. This would have you loop through all entries of alert_ul or the way I would do it is to simply keep a seperate array of all email addresses entered (don't forget to also remove the email from the array if the user clicks delete) where you can check if an email exists more easily than in the ul-list.

To ajax call your database script you would simply call this in your add-click function:

```
$.post( "dbstuff.php", { postMail: $('#alertinput').val(), action: "add" }, function(data) {
 if (data == "OK") {
// wait for response and add it to the list
  $('.alert_ul').append($('<li>', {
  text: $('#alertinput').val()
  }));

  $(".alert_ul li:last").append(deleteimage);
  alertinput.value = '';  
} else { alert ('Error inserting in DB'); } // something went wrong, an alert is probably not the best way to handle this ...
} );
```

for the delete part you would do something like this:

```
e.preventDefault();
var theListItem = $(this).parent().html();
$.post( "dbstuff.php", { postMail: theListItem, action: "delete" }, function(data) {
 if (data == "OK") {
   $(this).parent().remove();
 } else { alert ('Error deleting'); }   
});
```

The PHP file (I called it dbstuff.php) should then handle the add and delete action.
Also as posted before sanitize your data! There are a lot of smart ways to do that but as a start a simple

```
$selectedMail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postMail']);
```

helps you prevent the worst ;-)

then simply switch the action variable

```
$ret = "FAIL";
if ($action == "add") {
  if($update = $db->query("INSERT INTO alert_email(mail) VALUES ('".$selectedMail."')")) $ret = "OK";
}

if ($action == "delete") {
  if($update = $db->query("DELETE FROM alert_email WHERE mail='".$selectedMail."' LIMIT 1") $ret = "OK";
}

return ($ret);
```

This is a very quick an dirty example of how to do it. It's a good idea to implement more error checking (like if the variables are set) and maybe give the user more detailed feedback.

Also I didn't implement the array storage in the javascript example - I'll leave the duplicate check up to you ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try around with what you provided =)!

Comment: Havent had the time to try it out yet as we got other things to complete that had to be done this week. Will get on it next week!

Comment: No problem @AndreasKarlsson, just let me know if you need further assistance